# Android Accurate Speed Needed

Tags: android, gps, geolocation, location

My current project is base on GPS tracking, In that I can't able to retrieve the accurate speed from various devices comparing to iOS we get as 15 to 20 KM speed difference.

Folks, Is there any possible way to get an accurate GPS means kindly share it.

Comment: What are you doing at the moment to get the speed with which you are not satisfied?

Comment: At which speed do you measure?